# Get infopath XML content from Form Library using Client Object model and CEWP

Tags: infopath

I am using infopath to design my form and collect information from user in that form and submitting it in SharePoint Form library. Every thing was working good, Now my client wants me query for data to the generated xml infopath documents which are in form library. I can only use Content Editor web part, Jquery and Client object model with javascript.

Can someone help me on this issue

Comment: What is the overall objective ?

Answer (score 1):

In InfoPath there is option to fetch the data from the SharePoint List. So you can easily get the data from SharePoint list using Data Connection.

Open InfoPath Form in design mode.

Click to the Data tab in you InfoPath ribbon choose "From SharePoint List" Give the List URL and there a option to filter the data as per your query.

Check that link for more information.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-a-data-connection-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-or-list-HP010093160.aspx

Comment: Hi Basant, Yes we can create connection in infopath form but we can create connection with List and Library. As I have mentioned that I am submitting data in Form Library as XML files and I didn't find any way to establish connection with infopath xml files.

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpfull 
http://sujeewaediriweera.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/accessing-infopath-form-data-programmatically/

Use Xpath to extract data

Comment: Hi Sujeewa,   As I have mentioned in my question That I cannot write any code. I only can use CEWP, Jquery and Client Object Model i.e. ECMA Script.